# Entity to DTO conversion increases security

Tags: java, spring, dto

I have a question to ask regarding conversion of an Entity to DTO. I have read that it is good to convert the Entity to DTO in rest application so that it hides your entity data.
For e.g
If i have an entity User and there are two rest endpoints - GET and PUT. GET fetches the data and PUT updates the data. Now if i do not convert the Entity into DTO i would expose my Entity instances and someone could use the instance with PUT method and update the User Data.

But my question is this thing can also happen if i am using the same DTO class to convert the data while using the GET and PUT method (which most developers do). So how does conversion of entity to DTO increase security.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User{
private int id;
private int name;
private String password;
}
```

Please give you valuable comments to clarify this doubt of mine. Thanks!

Comment: `someone could use the instance with PUT method and update the User Data` - That's where authorization comes to the game. Only AUTHORIZED users should perform corresponding actions.

Comment: @J-Alex : That is fine .. I am asking how DTO helps in this regard?

Comment: @user3747182 have you find a good answer to this please? I don't understand who DTO can increase security !

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly define which attributes are available to your application's peripherals. I'm not sure this increases security, but it protects you from unwanted behavior. If you automatically convert your REST bodies to JSON via Jackson, every getter of your entity would be exposed. Hence if you add a getXXX method to evaluate something in your domain, you could unwillingly expose this to the outside world.

For instance you might not want to expose which authorizations are available for your user, or the user's password.

I like to use the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for REST/JMS interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Separation of concerns.

GET: In your example you would not return id back to the client would you?

PUT: You would not populate the id.